# OS X RSync from MAC to Windows share

Tags: macos, cron, rsync

I am trying to copy a list of text files from an OSx share to a windows shared folder on a network. I want this to happen at night and am scheduling using crontab.

For testing, I am using once a minute:  * * * * * /command

I have tried this:

```
  rsync /Users/MyName/Documents/Folder/*.txt /Volumes/WinShare/
```

and this:

```
  rsync /Users/MyName/Documents/Folder/*.txt /Volumes/WinShare
```

only the second works, however, when it does, it creates a folder on the windows share called "." (dot) and copies all files into that.

Can anyone assist in the correct syntax to copy my TXT files from siple origin to destination?

thanks.

Comment: What does the first do? Is the /Volumes/WinShare empty before your rsync in the first case? Try at least the `-vv` option for a bit more verbosity. Also, you might want to use options `-u`and `-t` to avoid copying unchanged files.

Comment: The first does nothing .. I dont know of any way to debug this as its being executed as a command within crontab ... the seond as I say does copy, but to this "," sub-folder 9which I assume is creating the root "." folder form OSx on the windows destination machine....

Comment: Cannot you debug it manually in the terminal? Then the -vv would reveal what goes wrong.